# Is ServiceStack.RabbitMQServer thread safe ? Can it start in task?

Tags: rabbitmq, servicestack

**Application**: .NET WebServer on ServiceStack using RabbitMQ to host services by class RabbitMQServer.

**Infrastructure**: WebServer and RabbitMQ are in diffrent Docker container.

**Problem**: During start WebServer App it has to RabbitMQServer.Start(), but connect failed becouse container with Rabbit not start yet.

I want try to check ability of connection to Rabbit and start RabbitMQServer in .NET Task. Is RabbitMQServer class thread safe ?

My code:

```
    ...
    RabbitMQServer _rabbitMqServer = ...;
    ...  
    public void Start()
    {
        Task.Run(() => TryToStart());
    }

    private void TryToStart()
    {
        var tryIndex = 0;
        const int tryCount = 10;
        const int tryTimeoutStep = 3000;
        const int tryMaxTimeout = 30000;
        while (tryIndex < tryCount)
        {
            tryIndex++;
            try
            {
                _logger.Info("Próba połączenia z RabbitMQ ...");
                ((RabbitMqMessageFactory) _rabbitMqServer.MessageFactory).ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection();

                // nie ma BrokerUnreachableException
                _rabbitMqServer.Start();
                return;
            }
            catch (BrokerUnreachableException e)
            {
                var millisecondsTimeout = Math.Min(tryTimeoutStep * tryIndex, tryMaxTimeout);
                _logger.Error($"{e.Message} - czekam {millisecondsTimeout / 1000}s ...");
                Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout);
            }
        }

        _logger.Error("Nie połączono z RabbitMQ!");
    }
```

Comment: Would you mind re-phrasing your question? I have no idea what you are trying to ask. RabbitMQ server is not an object and cannot be "thread safe" by that definition.

Comment: re-phrasing - done

Answer (score 0):

Always Dispose of connections you've created when you've finished using them.

Otherwise it's ok to call [RabbitMQ.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RabbitMQ.Client) `ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()` from multiple threads, but the connection returned should only be used by the Thread that created it, which should Dispose of it after use.

Comment: Thnx. I added a description to my question. We use DI - Autofac - it shoud call Dispose.

Comment: @Bernard No its not, your code is opening a zombie connection that's not being disposed. No IOC can manage the life-cycle of instances it didn't create or have registered with it. Either wrap your open connection in a `using(){}` or assign it to a variable that you can call `.Dispose()` of it after you no longer need it.

Comment: Ok. I put CreateConnection in "using", and if It doe not throw an BrokerUnreachableException, I'll do _rabbitMqServer.Start() in the same thread.

It's safe to use this RabbitMqServer in Services threads and Dispose in MainThread ?

Comment: @Bernard Yes that will dispose it.